# Tensor power of the natural representation of Sn

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

The symmetric group $S_n$ acts over $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ by permuting the canonical basis.

So it acts over $V^{\otimes p}$ with a diagonal action (acts the same over each element of the tensor product).

I'd like to find the decomposition into irreps of it. As I'm a physicist, I'm first interested in the simple cases $p=2$ (and if this is still difficult, $n=3,4$), even if something general would be nice!

I also need something constructive: I guess the proof will be constructive, but I'd prefer a reference where the basis vectors are easily tractable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question was recently completely solved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06543).

As explained on page 15 of the paper, letting $v_1,...,v_n$ be a basis for $V$, the standard basis vectors $v_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_p}$ for $V^{\otimes p}$ naturally correspond to partitions of the set $\{1,...,p\}$ into at most $n$ blocks.  The submodule corresponding to a particular partition into $t$ blocks is isomorphic to the permutation module $H^{(n-t,1^t)}=Ind_{S_{n-t}}^{S_n} 1$.  Multiplicities of irreducibles in $H^{\lambda}$ are well-known to be Kostka numbers $K_{\lambda, \mu}$, so we get that the multiplicity of the irreducible $S_{\lambda}$ in $V^{\otimes p}$ is $$\sum_{t=0}^n S(p,t) K_{\lambda, (n-t,1^t)}$$

Where $S(p,t)$ denotes the Stirling number.  The paper also gives a bijective proof of this equality using paths in the relevant Bratteli diagram.

The fact that you are working over $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{C}$ does not matter since all complex irreducible representations of $S_n$ can in fact be realized over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is this explicit, as in giving bases of the submodules?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, there is an explicit basis for the submodules $H^{(n-t,1^t)}$ which one can identify with $S_{n-t}$ cosets and thereby with Young tabloids and then follow the usual story.

Comment: Ah, I see! I was misled by the mentions of Schur-Weyl duality and semisimplicity. (NB: Stirling, not Sterling.)

Comment: Ok. To be sure that I understand, I do it on the simplest case n=p=2:
Basis $e_i\otimes e_j$
Partition $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1\},\{2\}$

The first partition corresponds to the "permutation module" $H_1=Span\{e_1\otimes e_1,e_2\otimes e_2\}$
The second partition corresponds to the "permutation module" $H_1=Span\{e_1\otimes e_2,e_2\otimes e_1\}$

Comment: $H_1$ and $H_2$ can be decomposed further (with $e_1\otimes e_1\pm e_2\otimes e_2, ...$) but this is well known (Kosta number...).

Thanks!

Comment: @MarcO  That's right.  If you want to understand explicit bases for the irreducibles appearing in $H^{\lambda}$ in general (rather than just multiplicites), this comes from the classical theory of Young tableaux and the like.  The section "The semistandard basis for $Hom(S^{\lambda}, H^{\mu})$" in Sagan's book "The symmetric group" is one exposition.  Also, if my answer is helpful, will you please accept it?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm not used to ask question here!

I didn't do a lot of group theory and I would like first to focus on a simple example. $n=p=2$ is easy, but it is less clear for me with $p=2$, $n=3$.

In the first permutation module, I find $\sum e_i\otimes e_i$ stable. I guess the orthogonal space irreducible?

In the second one, $\sum_{i\neq j} e_i\otimes e_j$ is stable. It have the intuition that there is more: If I add some - in the sum, it will be conserved...

Comment: In case the answer in that case is easy, could you give me the different basis vectors?

If not I'll go to a book and try to understand the notations...

Comment: (or maybe just the value of the Kostka numbers in that case? I'm a bit lost in all those notation.)

Comment: In the n=3, p=2 case: we get $H^{(2,1)}$ corresp. to the partition $\{\{1,2\}\}$, this is the one you called the first perm. module, and you are right that this is the sum of the trivial rep and an irreducible.  In general $H^{(n-1,1)} \cong V$ so it will always decompose like this.  We also get $H^{(1,1,1)}$ corresp. to the partition $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.  In general $H^{(1^n)}$ is the regular rep, so we get one copy of the trivial (given by the element you identified) one copy of the sign representation given by an alternating sum of $e_i \otimes e_j$'s and 2 copies of the 2-dim irrep.